# Convert Back to ES6 Classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I'm struggling what the equivalent syntax is for changing the following code to the equivalent ES6 syntax.

```
export default class EventSessionItem extends Component {
    state = {
        isDetailsVisible: false,
    };

    revealDetails = () => {
        this.setState({isDetailsVisible: true});
    };
```

I would have thought that the below would be the conversion but clearly not. It all lights up red as bad syntax.

```
export default class EventSessionItem extends Component {

  constructor() {
    isDetailsVisible = false;
  }

  function revealDetails  {
    this.setState({isDetailsVisible: true});
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Assuming you are using React.

```
export default class EventSessionItem extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isDetailsVisible: false
    }

    this.revealDetails = this.revealDetails.bind(this);
  }

  revealDetails() {
    this.setState({isDetailsVisible: true});
  }
}
```

The two class fields that you are using in the first example `state =` and `revealDetails = () =>` are not part of the standard yet. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: you'll also want a `this.revealDetails = this.revealDetails.bind(this)` in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your code with the class initialisers desugars to property assignments in the constructor:

```
export default class EventSessionItem extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
//^^^^^^^^^^^
    super(...args);

    this.state = {
//  ^^^^^
        isDetailsVisible: false,
    };

    this.revealDetails = () => {
//  ^^^^^
        this.setState({isDetailsVisible: true});
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this approach with some fixes from yours:**

```js
class Component {}
class EventSessionItem extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isDetailsVisible = false;
  }

  setState(newState) {
    this.isDetailsVisible = newState;
  }
  
  // This is to illustrate!
  getState() {
    return this.isDetailsVisible;
  }

  revealDetails() {
    this.setState({
      isDetailsVisible: true
    });
  };
}

var esi = new EventSessionItem();
esi.revealDetails();
console.log(esi.getState());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think he is using React, even though he didn't tag it.